# html javascript email image

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my validation script. Why doesn't it show a miniature, **red X image** when the email is entered but not correct? I'm stuck. Please help!

```
<form name="validation" onSubmit="return checkbae()">
    <input type="text" size=18 onkeyup="return checkbae()" name="email">
    <span id="email"   class="email"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
    function checkemail() {
        var messageg = document.getElementById('email');
        var str = document.validation.email.value
        var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]        {2})?)$/i
        if (filter.test(str))
            testresults = true
        else {
            messageg.style.color = red;
            messageg.innerHTML = "\u2718"
            testresults = false
        }
        return (testresults)
    }
    function checkbae() {
        if (document.layers || document.getElementById || document.all)
            return checkemail()
        else
            return true
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Created JSFiddle for this code: http://jsfiddle.net/p5Fha/

Comment: Please format your code, stop using bold and clearly state your problem.

Comment: I don't see you have declared testresults in your js file .

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn how to use a javascript debugger, such as Firebug.

First, you are missing a lot of semi-colons and brackets.  I know **some** of them are optional, but not using them will almost assuredly lead to headaches later down the road when you add another line of code, etc.  However, this is going to be a problem:

```
var str = document.validation.email.value   // <-- Semi-colon??
var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
```

After that, running your code immediately flagged an error that `red is not defined`.  You are using the bareword `red` instead of the string `"red"`.

Fixing that made it work.

```
function checkemail() {
    var messageg = document.getElementById('email');
    var str = document.validation.email.value;
    var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]        {2})?)$/i;
    if (filter.test(str)) {
        testresults = true;
    } else {
        messageg.style.color = "red";
        messageg.innerHTML = "\u2718";
        testresults = false;
    }
    return testresults;
}

function checkbae() {
    if (document.layers || document.getElementById || document.all) {
        return checkemail();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hFjPm/

**Note,** I just noticed that you are never clearing the `X` when the email is correct, so you will essentially *always* have the `X`.  You need to make sure to remove it in the `if` block of the filter.  With a little CSS, you can simplify your code as well, by simply hiding and showing the `X`, instead of recreating the html each time.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/txNTh/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this could help you but this is what i come up with.

```
<form name="validation" onSubmit="return checkbae();" method="post" >
    <input type="text" size="18" name="email" />
    <span id="email" class="email"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>



function checkemail() {
    var str = document.validation.email.value;
    var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    var testresults;
    if (filter.test(str))
        testresults = true;
    else {
        $(".email").text("\u2718").css("color", "red");
        testresults = false;
    }
    return (testresults);
}
function checkbae() {
    if (document.layers || document.getElementById || document.all)
        return window.checkemail();
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: OP is not using jQuery, so this will definitely not work.

Comment: @JeffB my bad, you right. I saw your example.